# how to trigger change event on current table rows index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Tbody of below table was cloned more than 2 or 3 so I will get more than 2 tbody that contain Class selector  **.mbody** and two of rows in a tbody. However I to used **Jquery Change** event to get the **provinces** data when a country selection was selected.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="addressList">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ trans('multiple.country') }}</th>
                <th>{{ trans('multiple.province') }}</th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="mbody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="country" name="country[]">
                     <option value="">-</option>
                        @foreach($country as $vals)
                             <option value="{{$vals['iso_code_3']}}" 
                                data-id="{{$vals['id']}}">
                                {{$detail['name']}}  {{$vals['id']}}
                             </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select class="provinces" id="provinces" name="provinces[]" style="width: 100%"></select>
                </td>

                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="return false"></a></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>   
                <td>
                    <label> Fields Khmer</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="fields_kh"></textarea>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label>Fields English </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="fields_en"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>        
</div>
```

Javascript:

I want to get the provinces data after country was selected on the current rows of this tables

```
$(document).on('change', 'tbody.mbody tr td', function (e) {
    "use strict";
    if(typeof country === 'undefined')return;

    var provinces = $('.provinces');
    var pro = '<option value="">-</option>';

    if ($(this).children('select').hasClass('country')) {

        var countryId = parseInt($(".country").select2("data").element[0].dataset['id'])

        provinces.select2('val', ''); 

        $.each(country, function (inx, vals) {

            if (parseInt(vals.id) === countryId) {

                $.each(vals.provinces, function (inx, prov) {

                    pro += '<option value="' + prov.prov_gis + '" data-id="' + prov.id + '"> ' + prov.eng_name + ' </option>';
                });
            }
        });

        provinces.empty().append(pro);
    }
});
```

Select2 don't wrap the provinces contain after append from JS

```
 provinces.empty().append(pro);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selectors to select the elements relative to your cloned tbody

```
  var provinces = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.provinces');
  var countryId = parseInt($(this).closest('tbody').find(".country").select2("data").element[0].dataset['id'])
```

When you clone the elements destroy the select2 before you clone them and then reinitialize it after the clone
to add elements use the select2 syntax

```
$("#select2").select2('data', {});
```

Comment: Oh i got error with select2 when using   provinces.empty().append(pro);
the content can not wrap with dropdown

Comment: use clone(true,true); to clone wuth the binded events

Comment: It still the same as i update please see the images that is province data. I will work as well if i used ID but as the current I used Class

Comment: If i used $('#province').empty().append(pro); instead of provinces.empty().append(pro); it will work but I don't want to add a ID to select.

Comment: @HengSopheak don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128328/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find provinces of current td on whose select the onchange is triggerd.

```
  var provinces = $(this).closest('tbody.mbody').find('.provinces');
```

Also the country should be fetched for current tbody.

```
  var countryId = parseInt($(this).closest('tbody.mbody').find(".country").select2("data").element[0].dataset['id']);
```